How to Add Authorization Header for API Scanning in OWASP ZAP with OpenAPI?
I'm using OWASP ZAP to scan an API, and I've successfully imported the OpenAPI definition. However, I'm struggling to configure the Authorization header (specifically for a JWT token) so that it is included in all requests sent by ZAP.
What I've Tried:
I added a Script-Based Authentication method and wrote a script to include the Authorization: Bearer  header.
I verified that the script is loaded correctly in the Scripts tab under the Authentication section.
I configured the script in the Session Properties -> Authentication panel for the context.
Even after setting this up, the requests sent by ZAP do not include the Authorization header. I'm currently using the the authentication default template to try to debug.

If you want to just include a specific header then use the Authentication Env Vars:
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE - if this is defined then its value will be added as a header to all of the requests
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER - if this is defined then its value will be used as the header name - if it is not defined then the standard Authorization header will be used
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_SITE - if this is defined then the header will only be included in sites whose name includes its value

For anything else start with the ZAP docs: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/
